# Example request: accusative neuter nouns in any classical prose text

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, accusative

Is anyone able to provide me with about five sentences from any Latin classical text (one or more), excluding poetry or plays, where a NEUTER noun (any) is unambiguously employed in the accusative as a direct object? There must be no other possible interpretation.

If you would be so kind as to provide the English translation as well and the source, I would be very grateful.

This request comes in connection with a linguistics project I am working on.

Thank you very much.
Harry.

EDIT: Even one such sentence would be very helpful as a start. I have not been able to find any so far.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you found any candidates yourself? We can help you verify a case.

Comment: I edited your post, but one thing I wasn't too sure on: you only want direct objects, right? I ask this because several prepositions and other adverbial uses can cause a noun to go into the accusative as well.

Comment: Thankyou for your kindness. I would appreciate having examples of direct objects in the first instance, but the other examples you mention would be most welcome as well.

Comment: Joonas, thankyou for your kind offer. No, I haven't yet found any examples. I have been looking mainly in Cicero's letters.

Answer (score 5):

There are several tools you could use to find this, but a free and reliable one is PHI Latin texts, which allows you to search for strings of characters within an author (or authors).

Knowing that the preposition *ad* takes an accusative, you could just [search for all instances of *ad* in Cicero](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ad%23+%5BCic%5D), which will lead you to find very early on the neuter noun [*vadimonium*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/1/4/2002-2005@1#4). This is an unambiguous example, then, of a neuter noun in the accusative (your earlier wording).

For neuter direct objects, you'll want to find a sentence with a transitive verb and a non-neuter nominative or, perhaps easier to do, a plural verb with a singular neuter. In that case, pick a neuter noun—any will do—and put it into PHI to search for it near "nt#", which will likely give you what you're looking for.

I chose *nomen* (wanted a different example from *vadimonium* and of course a clear and unambiguous neuter noun). Lo and behold, we have an answer:

> ...hos digitos meos impellere potui **ut falsum perscriberent nomen?**
> ...am I able to impel my fingers so that they write out a false name?

In this example, the ut-clause has only three words within it (aside from *ut*), an adjective, a neuter noun, and a plural verb. In this case, it's impossible that *nomen falsum* could ever be the subject of *perscriberent*. It's thus a clear and unambiguous example of a neuter noun accusative because it's a direct object.

Comment: A great answer that shows not just what the asker wanted but also how to find it. I would not have thought of that trick of searching near nt#!

Comment: I am very grateful to you and I sincerely thank you. I am new to this discipline (and to the Latin Stack Exchange) and am unfamiliar with PHI Latin texts (I was using Perseus, but fumbling about). You have given me a head start which will help me to find exactly what I need to find. Thankyou very much! Harry.